# Replace only on lines which contain no html tags

Tags: php, regex

My knowledge in the RegEx context is still not big enough. The example should demonstrate my problem - I hope. I parse a text and render HTML. Currently, my problem is to set the paragraph markup for each text, paragraph without a markup and a line ending.

### An example text:

```
<h1>Header</h1>\nA simple text with less of words. Yes much more lines.\n<h2>Tests</h2>\nThe solution is still active in his tests.\n
```

I like to add a simple paragraph `<p>` markup to each line (before `<p>` and after `</p>`), if it is without markup or an empty line, like `''`.

### The goal of the example below should looks like:

```
<h1>Header</h1>\n<p>A simple text with less of words. Yes much more lines.</p>\n<h2>Tests</h2>\n<p>The solution is still active in his tests.</p>\n
```

### I'm tried

My current RegEx parse that, but have the problem if I have a line is empty or after an empty line after a tag, like `</code>\n`.

```
'#(?![a-z][0-9]).(.*\n)#'
```

I tried also with negative look for closing the HTML tag like `#(?!\>).(.*\n)#`.

### Online test

https://regex101.com/r/khYWy4/2

Comment: [You should not parse HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Comment: regex matches lines opening and closing with the html tag.    <(([a-z]|[0-9])+)>(.*)<\/\1>

Comment: "No matter how many times we say it, they won't stop coming every day... every hour even. It is a lost cause, which someone else can fight for a bit. So go on, parse HTML with regex, if you must. It's only broken code, not life and death."

Comment: This is a far cry from *parsing* HTML. It's only asking for a substitution, and it should skip lines with html tags. It's something RegEx is equipped to handle just fine. As soon as someone says "HTML" and "RegEx" in the same sentence, SO waives that link about like the universe would suddenly collapse in on itself if you tried to touch HTML with RegEx.

Comment: Thanks @GrumpyCrouton for the helpful hint. So the link above helps to understand why we not should parse html. However is an task to change this, currently was the set pf the paragraph my last task on the library there I use, thats was the point that I have html include.

Comment: @Alex Karshin A hint or an why is enough, It is possible for me to learn.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use another tool if you can!

Depending on how you are going to use this, I will recommend that you find a solution which is not based on regex. This task is better solved by iterating the lines in a proper script or program, perhaps the one which generates the html in the first place, and injects the tags you need.

Having said that, I appreciate that sometimes there is no optimal solution.

#### My attempt to solve yor case

I have updated your example with a substitution which does seem to do what you want.

```
\n([^<>\n;]+?)\n
```

Substitute with

```
\n<p>\1</p>\n
```

#### The updated example:

https://regex101.com/r/khYWy4/3

Be aware of a few things here:

1. I ignore any lines which already contain any html tags.
2. I ignore any lines which contain a semicolon, to avoid

   tags in your code block.

### Disclaimer!

Depending on what other cases you have may look like, these simple skips were made just to make your example work. I can not guarantee that this will work for a larger set of data.

Comment: Thanks @melwil It is possible to get an solution without regex. The point was that I will more learn about regex. It is also possible to set the paragraph with pure php, without regex. If you like to see or interesting to see the current result, see https://github.com/bueltge/marksimple

Comment: Just explode the string on `\n`, then foreach through each line, and see what it contains. Add the tags where appropriate, then implode the array back on `\n`. I can see the point of learning more regex, and I encourage you to, but it is also important to see alternative ways to solve problems.

Comment: Yes, thats was my solution before I switch for more simplify the code, simple interface, see https://github.com/bueltge/marksimple/blob/1.0.0/src/MarkSimple.php#L122 However this simple file solution was not easy to test, I will enhance with unittest and an interfaces and his implements makes more solid.